# Why UITableview cell content zoom while scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have integrated a `tableview` in my project. I face the issue like when I scroll my tableview along with my `UITableViewCell` content zoom automatically. Although I didn't do any operation on `UITableViewCell` content, I have just animate the `UIView` which is above tableview.

Here is the snippet of my source code.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{

let scrollViewHeight = Float(scrollView.frame.size.height)
let scrollContentSizeHeight = Float(scrollView.contentSize.height)
let scrollOffset = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y)

    print(scrollOffset)
            if (scrollOffset == 0)
            {
                self.horizontalSpacing.constant = 8

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5)
                {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
            else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight <= scrollContentSizeHeight)
            {
                self.horizontalSpacing.constant = -75

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0)
                {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
      }
```

What I will do if I want to stop zooming the `UITableViewCell` content?

Answer (score 1):

swift 2.2: in my case: 
check func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {}
change any line self.view.frame.size.height to UISceeen.main.bounds.height.